# Trouble parsing CSV data when string contains a comma

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I am parsing a CSV data feed sent to me via php. I am turning each line into an array of values.

Here is my code:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt','r');

while (!feof($fp))
{
    $line = mysql_real_escape_string(fgets($fp));

    $value_array = explode(',', $line);
}
```

But if one of the lines looks like this:

> "some company, inc.",XC34ET,500

I am getting 4 values:

1. "some company
2. inc."
3. XC34ET
4. 500

When I really want these 3 values:

1. some company, inc.
2. XC34ET
3. 500

How can I update my script to account for this?

Comment: what ever function you us to read/parse the data don't apply mysql_real_escape_string() before you've parsed the csv data. mysql_real_escape_string() has a specific function, and it's _not_ parsing/escaping/unescaping csv data.

Comment: @VolkerK thanks I was wondering about that, so if I use greg0ire's suggestion of `fgetcsv` should I then call `mysql_real_escape_string` on each value in the returned array? Since I am going to put putting the values in a MySQL DB. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, like with any other string parameter you want to mix into the sql statement. But you could also use prepared statements and bound (named) parameters. In this case you first send the statement with placeholders for the parameters and then -in a separate step- the parameters, thus there are no characters in the parameters that might affect the statement -> no need for escaping + the statement has to be parsed only once even if you send multiple sets of parameters. see e.g. http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in function for parsing csv files: [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Just replace the fgets() call with it.
Using '"' as value for the $enclosure parameter should solve your problem .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to read in the line and parse it, returning an array

Comment: Since John is reading the data from a file fgetcsv($fp) seems to be the more "natural" thing to use...

Comment: Absolutely. It's late and I misread the question, but left it in for the sake of completeness!

Comment: Makes sense ;-) And since there are cases where one wants to parse csv data without a file pointer +1 from me...